# Azure Firewall connection reset

Tags: azure, firewall

We have a hybrid architecture using express-route and we send all traffics through Azure firewall even for on-prem connectivity.

I noticed that for some on-premise applications we get error

> Connection reset by peer

Accidentally I noticed if I don't send traffics through Azure firewall and directly sent to Microsoft Edge router I don't get that error and it works fine.

The required ports are open and I can telnet and connect to the destination.
What can be the reason for above error?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out we needed to add routes to virtual network gateway but still that's a question for me why did telnet work without adding routes?
After adding routes we didn't receive peer connection reset anymore.